# Callgrind: how to pass relative path to source code?

Tags: valgrind, callgrind, kcachegrind

I'm using valgrind's callgrind to profile a program and then kcachegrind to view the profile data. I've copied callgrind's output file to a different machine and have a copy of the source code there, but apparently the path information of the source code is baked into callgrind's format. This means kcachegrind is looking in the wrong place:

[image]

Is there a way to pass a relative source code path so that I can profile the program on one machine but then transport the profiling data to another machine and still view the source code?

Comment: Have you just tried to add the directory where you find divg.f90? I guess that this will work. Alternatively, do a 'sed' or similar on the callgrind file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had originally tried the sed route and that didn't work. But I looked at that solution again and the problem was that paths with '~' don't work with kcachegrind it seems.